# WM_CHAR send unicode character

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode, keyboard-hook

I'm hooking windows WM_CHAR message. When I'm replacing (in hook) given char code to something simple like 'a', every character I type is turning into a. And that's ok. But when I'm trying to send unicode character, like ф ('ф'.charCodeAt(0) gives 1092, so I'm replacing 'a' to 1092 in my code), all letters are turned into D. Also, when I type Alt+1092 in every text editor I'm getting D. Why? And can I send unicode char using WM_CHAR? Documentation says "The WM_CHAR message uses Unicode Transformation Format (UTF)-16.".

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Proc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(code >= HC_ACTION)
    {
        MSG* msg=(MSG *)lParam;
        if(msg->message==WM_CHAR)
        {
            int charCode = msg->wParam;
            if(IsCharLower(charCode))
            {
                charCode = 1092;
                msg->wParam=(WPARAM)charCode;
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
};
```

Comment: Is the window receiving this message created as a Unicode window? You can check by calling [`IsWindowUnicode(msg->hwnd)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633529.aspx). It appears that the upper byte of `wParam` gets masked out: Character 'ф' is U+0444, character 'D' is U+0044.

Comment: IsWindowUnicode returns true. Yes I realized this about upper byte, and wanted to simulate typing any unicode char directly from keyboard, and use Spy++ to know what message it is, but as I said in post: Alt+1092 also don't work :| So I have no idea how can I simulate it.

Comment: Why are you using messages to simulate keyboard input, instead of using `SendInput()` or similar function that are designed to handle this for you?

Comment: Because I want to use replace typed chars, not add new.